# iPad and iPhone calendar: same settings, different google calendars

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, calendar, google-calendar

Standard calendar app in iPad and iPhone show different calendars, while settings on "preferences/email, contacts and calendars" and in the standard calendar on both devices are equal, as far as i can see.
• On my iPad (mini iOs 6.1.3), my google(exchange) account shows just 1 calendar (with my google-address as name)
• On my iPhone (4s iOs 6.1.3), my google(exchange) account shows **6** calendars (with specified names, as online)
iCloud and others on both devices show same calendars.
How to let both devices show the same calendars?
*(and yes, on both devices i've already went to www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect and selected all ;)*

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Comment: haha... ask a question, what a great idea! ;)

Comment: What version of iOS are you using on each device? And you have them set up exactly the same way in the Settings app on each device?

Comment: @tubedogg - thanks for a reaction! iOs 6.1.3.  settings on "preferences/email, contacts and calendars" and in the standard calendar on both devices are equal, as far as i can see.